# how to implement while like loop in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I need help in implementing while like loop in xslt to convert any number to binary. On running this file it is showing following error on browser:

> Error during XSLT transformation: An unknown error has occurred ().

Just looking for a little logic to guide me.

Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="temp.xsl"?>
<catalog>
<data>2</data>
</catalog>
```

Below is the xslt file, it seems there is problem in calling "loop" function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name ="loop" >
            <xsl:with-param name="var" select="catalog/data"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="temp" select= "$var div 2"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="data" select= "$var mod 2"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="loop">
<xsl:param name="var"></xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="temp"></xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="data"></xsl:param>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test= "$temp &gt; 0">
    <xsl:value-of select="$data"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="loop">
        <xsl:with-param name="var"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$data mod 2"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="temp" select="$temp div 2"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select= "$data"/> 
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

div is not integer division - so you get infinite recursion.
Add floor

Also - seems to me var is not used inside the loop

And `<xsl:value-of select= "$data"/>` is present in both branches - so it could be moved outside the condition and choose could be changed to if

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="var"><xsl:value-of select="catalog/data" /></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:call-template name="loop">
         <xsl:with-param name="temp" select="floor($var div 2)" />
         <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$var mod 2" />
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template name="loop">
      <xsl:param name="temp" />
      <xsl:param name="data" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$data" />
      <xsl:if test="$temp &gt; 0">
         <xsl:call-template name="loop">
            <xsl:with-param name="temp" select="floor($temp div 2)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$data mod 2" />
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```